# Using SQL Report Builder How can I filter out all Id's with every value NE another field value?

Tags: sql, reportbuilder

I'm new to Report builder and am trying to figure out how to exclude id's (multiple value) when every of another field (single value each) are NE to a defined value.  For example filter the person id, when every Award NE Scholarship1.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details and code. Do you have a script for your query? Sample tables and data too if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to create a filter after you have created the table
Right click on the table and select tablix properties, go to filters and clidd the create new filter button.

Then you need to define the filter expression which will set what needs to be filtered.
In the "Expression" box, select the field for Awards (e.g., [Award]).
In the "Operator" box, select "!=" to represent "not equal to."
In the "Value" box, enter "Scholarship1.

This will include only the rows where the award is not equal to scholarship1

Apply the filter to the dataset
Ensure to select the dataset you are working on for the tablix properties